# Wordpress display Full Blog post Title (Twenty Twelve Theme)

Tags: php, wordpress

I use Twenty Twelve Wordpress theme and after a lot of tests and searches, I can't display the full blog post title on my home page...

I changed content.php file and code this :

```
<h1 class="entry-title">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
</h1>
```

But it display me the excerpt...

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you using this piece of code inside the loop? See the description paragraph of this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title. If you're outside the loop you need to use get_the_title() function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mbecares, Yes I use it inside of the loop :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please paste your code in for loop :

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
         <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
</h1>
<?php endwhile;
else :
    echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
endif;
?>
```

Comment: OMFG !!!!!!!!!!

I'm a crazy idiot! 

Since the begining EVERYTHING WORKS FINE! 

I'd just don't wrote the good title and I copy/paste a title with "..." at the end... 

An entire week-end lost!

Thanks a lot to tried to help me... but you can't resolve stupidity.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since i have used WordPress but as far as i remember there are to setting stetting for the website and settings for the theme .

in the theme setting there should be a show and hide site title just check that . 
that should help .

No code needed .

Comment: Yes you can setting to display the excerpt or the full content in Wordpress setting, but only for content, not for title. 
I tried to set it in full content, but no change.
Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just use Posts in Page plugin this allow you to add the post with full title to and page on your website including your home page

Comment: Good idea! I'll try it after work! 
But even if it work, it's a trick.. I hoped a native solution. :-)
(But if it works I'll not complain!)

Comment: I have used that plug in before and i found it work fine . 
best of luck with